# Binding a table adapter query to a chart

Tags: c#, charts, zedgraph

I'm writing some code that will synchronize data in a database with a chart (it's [ZedGraph](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx), in fact - but it doesn't matter). 
I want to do something like this:

- chart draws data from the databse
- whenever new data is added to database, it's immediately drawn on the chart

So far everything works OK, because I can bind chart line DataSource to a data table.  But I also want to draw a moving average of the values on the chart.
So I used Table Adapter to write a query that calculates the moving average and returns the result. Then I created a new chart line and bind it to the result of a query:

```
it = new DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.IntradayAdapter();
line.DataSource = it.GetSMABy(name);
```

Is it possible, that whenever new data is added to the database, it gets drawn on the chart and recalculates the moving average without any action listeners?

Comment: FYI action listener  is a Java concept. In C# we have `events` and `delegates`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SQL Server Notification Services](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/notification-services.aspx) to push updates to your client, at which point it could update the graph.

Although it hasn't been updated in a while, you may want to check out [WPF Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/).  It's a charting library with some great features, and includes lots of useful samples, some of which update the charts in real time.